# How get key value in vuejs in v-for directive?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

i have this on vue template:

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
  <!-- content -->
</div>
```

i want get the value of item.id and send via axios.

i dont know how bind de value from template to script section.

Answer (score 5):

You can put a button with a on click handler inside the div:

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
  <button @click="sendItem(item.id)">Send</button>
</div>
```

And define the handler in `methods` section:

```
<script>
export default {
data: ...
methods: {
    sendItem: function(itemId) {
        // Using axios here
    }
}
}
</script>
```